# Stopping whole test suite if one specific test case failed

Tags: unit-testing, robotframework

I'm trying to stop a test suite from continuing after a specific test case fails.

For Example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
|Log In 
|           |Perform Valid Login 
|Test A
|           |Do A 
|Test B
|           |Do B
```

I need to stop the test suite **Only** if the Log in fails. Is there any keyword I can use when I define the "Perform Valid Login" keyword or is it something that needs to be done from the "Suite Teardown" (and if so how).

If I run the keyword "Run Keyword if Test Failed" it will stop the test suite if any test case will fail. Meaning if there is a problem with "Test A" it will stop and not continue to "Test B".

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the built-in keyword [Fatal Error](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Fatal%20Error) to cause the execution to be halted. From the documentation:

> Stops the whole test execution.
>
> The test or suite where this keyword is used fails with the provided
>   message, and subsequent tests fail with a canned message. Possible
>   teardowns will nevertheless be executed.

You could put this in a test teardown, and only call it if the test failed:

```
*** Test Cases ***
| Log In
| | [Teardown] | Run keyword if test failed
| | ... | Fatal Error | Unable to log in
```

Of course, you can also call `Fatal Error` directly in your keyword if you want. Instead of `Run keyword if test failed` you would use the normal `Run keyword if` statement, and provide it some test that can determine if the login was successful or not.

Generally speaking, having tests dependent on other tests is considered poor test design. Any given test shouldn't depend on any other. For example, this setup would prevent a developer from running only "Test B", since "Test B" relies on "Log In" having been run first.

Sometimes it's unavoidable, but if this is more of a setup step rather than an actual test case, you might want to consider moving the login to a suite setup. If the suite setup fails, all other tests will fail instantly with a message stating that the suite setup failed.

Another option would be to add a special keyword that asserts you are properly logged in. Then,  you make this a test setup keyword for every test but the login test. When each test runs, the first thing it would do is check to see if it is logged in or not, and can fail instantly if not.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough. 
Fatal Error causes manual stoppage. I need to stop the test suite if the test case failed during the test.

Comment: @PurpleBeni: I don't understand your comment. What is "manual stoppage"? Have you tried using `Fatal Error` to see what it does?

Comment: Yes I have. It runs the test case and when it comes to that code line it stops the test. I need to stop only if there was an error in the test case caused by the program (not a manual error I inserted like Fatal Error).

Comment: @PurpleBeni: I'm sorry. I assumed you knew you could run that test via "Run Keyword If". I'll try to clarify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should define a Suite setup that does the login.

That way, if the login fails - the entire suite fails.

Alternatively - You can also define the Perform Valid Login Test in the following way:

```
Login Test
    Perform Valid Login
    [teardown]  Run Keyword If Test Failed  Fatal Error
```